# emacs helm-projectile, slow startup and projectile file find very slow

Tags: emacs, projectile, emacs-helm

I'm on emacs using helm-projectile. I notice that emacs startup is very slow, ~4s. And projectile find fuzzy matching is slow as well, when I type the file name in full it takes about ~3s.

I am working on a very large project, ~110K files. Is there someway I can exclude from folders from the search path?

Comment: Have you tried  (setq projectile-indexing-method 'alien) or .projectile file to exclude stuff?

Answer (score 2):

I found a huge speedup by enabling Projectile's caching.

To turn it on, M-x customize-variable for `projectile-enable-caching` and set it to on.

Docs: https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile/blob/master/doc/configuration.md#caching

> Since indexing a big project is not exactly quick (especially in Emacs Lisp), Projectile supports caching of the project's files. The caching is enabled by default whenever native indexing (editor's note: native indexing is for Windows) is enabled.